# Установка делений оси Y в matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Суть проблемы: при выводе графиков с помощью `matplotlib` появляются неправильные деления. Вопрос в том, как установить нужные.

Есть таблицы с оценками в `pandas.DataFrame`: что то вроде:
`Dec = pandas.DataFrame()`

`DataFrame` `Dec`:

```
8: 5
9: 5
11: 4
15: 4
17: 3
20: 5
```

И точно такой же `DataFrame` ноября: `Nov`.

Первое число - день месяца, второе - оценка.

И вывод графика:

```py
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(10, 5))
axs[0].plot(Nov)
axs[1].plot(Dec)
```

И вот проблем: оценки идут по 5-балльной системе, а график выводит вот такое:

[image: График]

Поскольку оценки у ученика в основном `5` и `4` за этот предмет, слева появляются ненужные цифры: `4.8`, `4.6`, `4.2`, а мне нужны оценки от `2` до `5`.
Я долго искал решение, в виде какого-то аргумента или функции, которое меняло бы это, но так и не нашёл.
Если кто-то знает, как это сделать, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

Вашу проблему должно решить декларирование yticks через [set_yticks](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticks.html)

```
axs[0].set_yticks((2, 3, 4, 5))
axs[1].set_yticks((2, 3, 4, 5))
```

Comment: Если не установить нужные пределы с помощью `set_ylim`, то графики поломаются.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема, с которой вы столкнулись, связана с автоматической настройкой диапазона значений по оси Y на графиках, созданных через `plot()` в `matplotlib`. По умолчанию `matplotlib` устанавливает пределы оси Y, основываясь на значениях данных, что может привести к неожиданному масштабированию.

Чтобы решить эту проблему и установить нужные пределы по оси Y, вам следует использовать методы `set_ylim()` для каждого из ваших графиков. Вот как это можно сделать:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Предположим, что у вас есть DataFrame'ы Dec и Nov с данными

# Создание графиков
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(10, 5))

# Отображение данных на графиках
axs[0].plot(Nov)
axs[1].plot(Dec)

# Установка желаемых пределов по оси Y для каждого графика
axs[0].set_ylim(2, 5)  # Желаемые пределы для левого графика
axs[1].set_ylim(2, 5)  # Желаемые пределы для правого графика

# Отображение графиков
plt.show()
```

В вашем случае, если вам нужно явно указать, какие значения должны быть отображены на оси Y (например, 2, 3, 4 и 5), вы можете использовать `set_yticks()` для этого. Вот пример использования:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Предположим, что у вас есть DataFrame'ы Dec и Nov с данными

# Создание графиков
fig, axs = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(10, 5))

# Отображение данных на графиках
axs[0].plot(Nov)
axs[1].plot(Dec)

# Установка желаемых пределов и делений по оси Y для каждого графика
axs[0].set_ylim(2, 5)
axs[0].set_yticks([2, 3, 4, 5])
axs[1].set_ylim(2, 5)
axs[1].set_yticks([2, 3, 4, 5])

# Отображение графиков
plt.show()
```

Установка пределов с помощью `set_ylim` во втором примере тоже нужна, потому что иначе графики поломаются.